# Jest component mock with enzyme shallow toMatchSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest

Пытаюсь сделать проверку компонента по snapshot-у с помощью enzyme.shallow. Все идет нормально, пока, я не попытался сделать AutoMock компонента и не откомментировал `jest.mock('./Calendar');`

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from "enzyme-to-json";
import moment from "moment";
import Calendar from './Calendar';

// jest.mock('./Calendar');

describe('Calendar component', () => {
  const props = {}
  const state = {
    selectedMonth: moment('2000–01–01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'),
    selectedDay: moment('2000–01–01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
  }

  describe('render', () => {
    it('match Calendar to snapshot', () => {
      const calendarSnapshot = shallow(<Calendar {...props} />);
      calendarSnapshot.setState(state)

      expect(shallowToJson(calendarSnapshot)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  })
})
```

Вылетает ошибка [image: Теперь в shallow ничего не приходит]

Как мне сделать проверку по snapshot-у и одновременно сделать мок компонента?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью calendarSnapshot.instance(). Это мне и нужно было в дальнейшем, чтобы тестировать методы класса, мок убрал

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Прикрепите к ответу блок кода с Вашим решением, чтобы в дальнейшем ответ был полезным для других участников SO.